# Empty Ext4 Filesystem Using Too Much Space

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, arch-linux

I have 3 primary partitions on my main drive (2 are primary, 1 is extended and has 3 logical partitions in it). The drive has a legacy BIOS/MBR partition table. The first 2 primaries have OSes in them (Win7 and PC-BSD). The first 2 of the logicals are empty and formatted as NTFS. The 3rd logical is 550GB Ext4 and will soon have Arch installed into it. I created/formatted the partitions with GParted, in advance, before installing any OSes, to avoid any visible free space gaps between the partitions (don't know why, but it irritates me to no end, and I go to long lengths to avoid it).

I also have a 2nd internal drive in my laptop, which has partitions with varying filesystems, including numerous Ext4 Linuxes, and when I initially created them their empty filesystems didn't consume such a large portion of the partition (usually 100MB or less). So it confounds the crap out of me that the partition prepared for Arch has nothing in it, yet it shows 8GB as being used.

I'm wondering if someone can shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> By default, 5% of available disk space is reserved for the root user.
>   This is usually a good thing for the partition where the / directory
>   is mounted, but it may be not desiderable on other partitions. If you
>   don't want to reserve disk space for the root user you can use the -m
>   0 option:

Taken from [here](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Ext4)

Comment: I know about the 5% reserved for root, I've seen it while installing some distros. My partition is approx 550GB. Maybe I'm mistaken, but my calculations are that approx 27.5GBshould be reserved for root, assuming your calculations are correct. But again, only slightly more than 8GB are being used. I have just 1 partition, with /, no other partitions are allocated for use by Arch, with the exception of a 6GB swap partition on the 2nd physical drive (Arch isnt being installed on that drive. The swap partition will be shared between Arch, Mint, and Kali, to save space. But swap should no effect o

Comment: I know about the 5% reserved, I've seen it before. My partition is 550GB. Maybe I'm mistaken, but my calculations are that 27.5GBshould be reserved for root, if you're right. But only slightly more than 8GB are being used. I have 1 partition, with /, no other partitions are allocated for use by Arch, except a 6GB swap partition on the 2nd HDD, which will be shared between Arch, Mint, and Kali, to save space. So, either the calculations are incorrect, or something else is causing the (perceived?) discrepancy.

Comment: Well, you can see how much space is reserver for root user with `dumpe2fs` command

Comment: I apologize, but I'm still confused. Should I upload Gparted screenshots of both of my drives? Any other details needed? I'm just curious more than anything else.